# Need suggestion to create indexing and searching using lucene.net

Tags: azure, storage, blob, lucene.net

I have to build lucene index on azure storage, do I have to create two worker roles one for search and one to create/update documents? Also if i want to rebuild the index after every new  document creation. Please suggest me the best way.

Thank you,
Ravi krishna.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are asking very generic info. For specific question you need to be very specific. Actually you can have one Windows Azure Worker Role for Index creation and then you can use one Web Role for Search. It is very much possible to put together both process in one Web Role as well. You can use nuget Lucene.NET package directly and then you can configure the search and index creation.

Take a look at [Lucene/Solr](http://www.lucidimagination.com/content/scaling-lucene-and-solr#d0e58) which is Java based library and you can run as Service to manage Indexes. You sure can use Solr with Lucene.net.

Here are some resources to start with:

- [Simple Lucene](http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/SimpleLucene-e28093-Lucenenet-made-easy.aspx)
- [Lucene.Net Tutorial (covers version 2.9.2)](http://www.d80.co.uk/post/2011/03/29/LuceneNet-Tutorial.aspx)
- [Azure Directory](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AzureDirectory)